# Custom phtml not getting called from the Block magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template

On a button click, when my controller redirects to a new form, i want my custom phtml file to be called from the block.

But neither my Block or my phtml does seem to be called.

I guess I have missed some link somewhere

I have done as below:

**config.xml**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Vendor_Recipe>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Vendor_Recipe>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <vendor_recipe>
            <class>Vendor_Recipe_Block</class>
        </vendor_recipe>
    </blocks>

    <models>
        <vendor_recipe>
            <class>Vendor_Recipe_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vendor_recipe_resource</resourceModel>
        </vendor_recipe>

    </models>

</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <vendor_recipe>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Vendor_Recipe</module>
                <frontName>vendor_recipe</frontName>
            </args>
        </vendor_recipe>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <vendor_recipe>
                <file>vendor_recipe.xml</file>
            </vendor_recipe>
        </updates>
    </layout>

</frontend>
```

I have a button here:

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\vendor_recipe\recipe\customer\comment\list.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<div class="page-title">
  <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('vendor_recipe/manageRecipe/addRecipe') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">

    <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add New Recipe') ?>">
        <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add New Recipe') ?></span></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Where in :

**\app\code\local\Vendor\Recipe\controllers\ManageRecipeController.php**

```
  <?php
 class Vendor_Recipe_ManageRecipeController extends  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
 {
 public function addRecipeAction()
{
    //echo 'Add recipe';
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

}
```

Calling **addrecipe**.phtml from layout as:

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\vendor_recipe.xml**

```
<vendor_recipe_recipe_customer_manage translate="label" module="vendor_recipe">
    <label>My Recipes </label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="vendor_recipe/recipe_customer_managerecipe" name="customer_recipe_add" template="vendor_recipe/recipe/customer/managerecipe/addrecipe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</vendor_recipe_recipe_customer_manage>
```

**\app\code\local\Vendor\Recipe\Block\Recipe\Customer\ManageRecipe.php**

```
class Vendor_Recipe_Block_Recipe_Customer_ManageRecipe extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Dashboard
{

  protected function _construct(){
      echo 'Block ';
  }
```

}

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\vendor_recipe\recipe\customer\managerecipe\addrecipe.phtml**

```
<?php
    echo 'ADD';die;
?>
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

your xml file contail wrong block name update with below one

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\vendor_recipe.xml**

```
<vendor_recipe_recipe_customer_manage>
 <label>My Recipes </label>
 <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
       <block type="vendor_recipe/recipe_customer_managerecipe" name="customer_recipe_add" template="vendor_recipe/recipe/customer/managerecipe/addrecipe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</vendor_recipe_recipe_customer_manage>
```

or change your layout file as below

```
<customer_account>
   <reference name="content">
        <block type="vendor_recipe/recipe_customer_managerecipe" after="my.account.wrapper" name="customer_recipe_add" template="vendor_recipe/recipe/customer/managerecipe/addrecipe.phtml"/>
   </reference>  
<customer_account>
```

Comment: I have updated the code for button and the controller...am i missing any link to the Block?

Comment: please provide your config.xml for more detail

Comment: added the config file

Comment: @SachinS check my updated answer

Comment: If i use the <customer_account> tag, my custom link from the left navigation of the customer account is not coming

Comment: any update @Murtuza... cause i have used <customer_account> already for defining the controller and custom link in the left navigation

Comment: in `<customer_account>` place your block according to position using before after attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not properly named.

You need to replace:

```
Vendor_Recipe_Block_Recipe_Customer_Manage
```

With:

```
Vendor_Recipe_Block_Recipe_Customer_ManageRecipe
```

And in your layout replaced:

```
vendor_recipe/recipe_customer_manage
```

With:

```
vendor_recipe/recipe_customer_manageRecipe
```

Comment: I have updated the code @Raphael, phtml is still not calling...and should we give managerecipe or manageRecipe in layout?